# extjs twinText focus when click on trigger

Tags: extjs5

I have a TextFiled component, where add clear trigger. like this one:

```
 this.config.triggers = {
        clear: {
            cls : (Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'form-clear-trigger'),
            handler : function() {
                this.setValue();                 
            }
        }

    }
```

...
So, and I handle an event focus

```
 this.text= Ext.create('TwinText', {
        width: 400,
        emptyText: 'dddd',
        listeners: {
            scope: this,
            focus:  this.show,             
        },
        editable : false
    });
```

Now, when I click on trigger clean, the focus event was fired. How can I suspend this?

Comment: The focus event is fired before the trigger click, so it's not possible to prevent focus on combo when the trigger (that is inside de combo) is clicked. You can prevent focus by setting "focusable:false" to the combo but focus event will never be fired. What is your use case? My idea is that you are listening for the wring event "focus".

Comment: After click on TextFiled I would like to open some window(panel), but TextField doesn't  have any 'click' event and that's why I use focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the click event to your Textfield component instead of using focus.

Ex. in the TwinText definition add:

```
initEvents: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.mon(this.inputEl, 'click', this.onClick, this);
},

onClick: function (e) {
    this.fireEvent('click', this, e);
}
```

then listen for the "click" event instead of "focus".